# Asking Mediastore cursor for .DATA results in forced close

Tags: android

I have a cursor that queries the MediaStore depending on the keyword entered.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        uri, 
                        projection,
                        where,
                        params,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
```

I can access the ID, title, artist etc without any problems but whenever I query the .DATA line I get an error stating that I should make sure the cursor is initialized correctly before attempting to access data from it.

```
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
    String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
 /** ERROR IN THIS LINE **/   String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
    test.setText(title +" " + artist + " " + data);
                            cursor.close();


                }
```

Logcat :

```
08-14 14:08:43.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4428): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
08-14 14:08:43.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
08-14 14:08:43.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
08-14 14:08:43.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
08-14 14:08:43.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4428):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
```

and it points at that line of my activity.

If I remove the string data, I get title, album name, artist name, song ID etc perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I fixed it. I didn't have Mediastore.Audio.Media.DATA inside my query projection.

This may stay for anyone who needs it in the future.